# Django api - How to use DestroyAPIView and maintain RESTfulness

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

How would one use Django `DestroyAPIView` and `DetailAPIView` and still maintain generally accepted practices of *RESTfulness*?

If I understand *REST* correctly it should work as follow (only one example)

```
/api/game/222
```

then 1 view class(`generics.DetailAPIView`) or method, in Django would be created to handle the call

In a REST world, I believe we would use a generic API class to handle the 
methods (get,...)

But if I wanted to use the class(`generics.DestroyAPIView`) to handle the calls to delete a game.
then I would have to use

```
/api/game/delete/222
```

to send the request to the correct view.

It seems to me this is not consistent with *RESTFULness*.
for the delete method of the HTTP should be used to send the delete request and use the same pattern matching `/apt/game/222` to delete the game.  It's redundant.

Question: Am I missing something?

**In summary**

**option 1:**

```
/api/game/delete/222 (DestroyAPIView)
/api/game/detail/222 (DetailAPIView)
```

**option 2**

```
/api/game/222 (RetrieveDestroyAPIView)
```

I guess either way works, and as long as it's clear and consistent as stated below.  There is no "*right*" way.

Comment: You can just send a `DELETE` verb to `/api/game/222` in order to delete the game. This is one of the basic concepts behind REST.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I not sure 'RESTFULness' affect what you are asking here. It is perfectly fine to have different matching pattern as long as it make sense.

In the example given, usually we do not have `/api/game/222` as a `generics.ListCreateAPIView`. This is because `List` return a list of all game, we do not pass a `id` in. `Create` is trying to create a new `Game`. You do not have `id` yet because it is not in database, therefore both of the matching pattern should usually be `/api/game/` instead.

`/api/game/222` - such pattern, we usually use for `generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView` because with a given `id` in url, we can get the correct `Game` object to either retrieve, update or delete it.

Regarding the Restful API, the answers in this [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/671118/what-exactly-is-restful-programming) explain more about 'Restfulness'.

Comment: i updated the question to better reflect what i was asking.  But I believe the answer is your first sentence.  "as long as it makes sense"